# How can I index a function with the type of dataset used

Tags: function-construction, code-review, code-generation

I have the following `code` which serves my purpose for a single matrix input. For one or two matrices, the operation can be done manually, but I have 65 matrices and need to run the same `code` for all of the 65 matrices and keep each output with an index name.

```
ClearAll[vLabels, legends];
<< IGraphM`;
<< BoolEval`;
SeedRandom[13];
a1=RandomReal[{0.1, 0.5}, {10, 10}];
vLabels = {1 -> A1, 2 -> B1, 3 -> C1, 4 -> D1, 5 -> E1, 6 -> F1, 
     7 -> G1, 8 -> J1, 9 -> K1, 10 -> L1};
legends = {"AGF","CO12","MA1","MA2","EGW","WHS","HOT","TSC","FIN","EST"};
selectBetweenCRI[θ1_, θ2_] := 
BoolEval[θ1 <= a1 < θ2];
subgraphBetweenCRI[θ1_, θ2_] := 
AdjacencyGraph[selectBetweenCRI[θ1, θ2], 
  PlotLabel -> θ1 <= Subscript[m, ij] < θ2, 
  VertexSize -> 0.3, VertexLabels -> vLabels, ImagePadding -> 20, 
  ImageSize -> 150];
{
{"CRI_Weighted index of total number of links", 
 Sum[ θ1*
    EdgeCount[subgraphBetweenCRI[θ1, Max[a1]]], {θ1, 0, 
    Max[a1], 0.01}]},
ListLinePlot[
Table[{θ1, θ1*
    EdgeCount[subgraphBetweenCRI[θ1, Max[a1]]]}, {θ1, 
    0, Max[a1], 0.01}], 
AxesLabel -> {"Threshold \nmultiplier: \\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(CRI\)]\)", "Weighted index \nof linkages: I(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \\(CRI\)]\))"}]
 }
```

I tried the following but I am stuck with it:

```
ClearAll[vLabels, make, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, selectBetween, 
 subgraphBetween];
SeedRandom[13];
vLabels = {1 -> A1, 2 -> B1, 3 -> C1, 4 -> D1, 5 -> E1, 6 -> F1, 
   7 -> G1, 8 -> J1, 9 -> K1, 10 -> L1};
make[] := RandomReal[{0.1, 0.5}, {10, 10}];
{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6} = {make[], make[], make[], make[], make[], 
  make[]};

selectBetween[m_?MatrixQ, θ1_, θ2_] := 
   BoolEval[θ1 <= m < θ2];
subgraphBetween[m_?MatrixQ, θ1_, θ2_] := 
   AdjacencyGraph[selectBetween[m, θ1, θ2], 
   PlotLabel -> θ1 <= Subscript[m, ij] < θ2, 
   VertexSize -> 0.3, VertexLabels -> vLabels, ImagePadding -> 20, 
   ImageSize -> 150];
sum[m_?MatrixQ, θ1_, θ2_] := 
Sum[ θ1*
EdgeCount[subgraphBetween[m, θ1, θ2]], {θ1, 
0.1, θ2, 0.01}];

ListLinePlot[
  Table[{θ1, θ1*
  EdgeCount[subgraphBetween[m, θ1, θ2]]}, {θ1, 
  0, θ2, 0.01}]]
```

> UPDATE

This generates the result I want, but I think there is a more elegant way to do this.

```
<< IGraphM`;
<< BoolEval`;

SeedRandom[13];
vLabels = {1 -> AGF, 2 -> CO12, 3 -> MA1, 4 -> MA2, 5 -> EGW, 
   6 -> CST, 7 -> WHS, 8 -> HOT, 9 -> TSC, 10 -> FIN};
legends = {AGF, CO12, MA1, MA2, EGW, CST, WHS, HOT, TSC, FIN};

make[] := RandomReal[{0.1, 0.5}, {10, 10}];
{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6} = {make[], make[], make[], make[], make[], 
  make[]};

{
out[#]= {
selectBetweenCRI[\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_] := 
BoolEval[\[Theta]1 <= # < \[Theta]2];
subgraphBetweenCRI[\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_] := 
AdjacencyGraph[selectBetweenCRI[\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2],
  PlotLabel -> \[Theta]1 <= Subscript[m, ij] < \[Theta]2, 
  VertexSize -> 0.3, VertexLabels -> vLabels, ImagePadding -> 20, 
  ImageSize -> 150];

{
  {"CRI_Weighted index of total number of links", 
  Sum[ \[Theta]1*
   EdgeCount[
    subgraphBetweenCRI[\[Theta]1, Max[mmCRI]]], {\[Theta]1, 0, 
   Max[mmCRI], 0.01}]},
sectorCRI = {legends, 
     Sum[\[Theta]1*
       DegreeCentrality[
        subgraphBetweenCRI[\[Theta]1, Max[mmCRI]]], {\[Theta]1, 0,
        Max[mmCRI], 0.01}]}\[Transpose] // Reverse // TableForm,
ListLinePlot[
 Table[{\[Theta]1, \[Theta]1*
    EdgeCount[
     subgraphBetweenCRI[\[Theta]1, Max[mmCRI]]]}, {\[Theta]1, 0, 
   Max[mmCRI], 0.01}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"Threshold \nmultiplier: \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\
 \[Theta]\), \(CRI\)]\)", 
   "Weighted index \nof linkages: I(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\
 \), \(CRI\)]\))"}]
 }
 }} & /@ {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: To reduce the work of the `Community Expert` like you, editing my questions, I like to know how you inserted `θ1` in place of `\Theta` alike. Can you tell me how you replaced these terms?

Comment: If you are using Chrome then use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathematica-editor-button/jelneigihibbkognjehbbembccihhbnb?hl=en)

Comment: @Rohit: I did not understand what you meant. I went to the link you refer to but then wht should I do?

Comment: It is a Chrome extension. Add it to Chrome from the link and buttons will appear on the top left of the "Ask Question" and "Answer" forms. More details [here](https://github.com/halirutan/SE-Editor-Buttons).

Comment: [halirutan's buttons extension](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/121) is available for other browsers as well, like Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo = Module[{mat = #, max = Max[#], legends = #2, vlabels = Thread[Range[Length@#] -> #2], 
      subgraphBetweenCRI, wecnt, windex, degcent, llp}, 
    subgraphBetweenCRI = AdjacencyGraph[UnitStep[mat - #] (1 - UnitStep[mat - #2])] &;
    wecnt = #*EdgeCount[subgraphBetweenCRI[#, max]] &;
    windex = Sum[wecnt[t], {t, 0, max, 0.01}];
    degcent = Sum[t*DegreeCentrality[subgraphBetweenCRI[t, max]], {t, 0, max,  0.01}];
    llp = ListLinePlot[Table[{t, wecnt[t]}, {t, 0, max, 0.01}], 
      AxesLabel -> {"Threshold \nmultiplier:" <> 
         ToString[Subscript[\[Theta], CRI], StandardForm], 
        "Weighted index \nof linkages: " <> 
         ToString[ Subscript[I\[Theta], CRI], StandardForm]}];
    {{"CRI_Weighted index of total number of links", windex},
     TableForm@Reverse@Transpose[{legends, degcent}], llp}] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[13];
vLabels = {1 -> AGF, 2 -> CO12, 3 -> MA1, 4 -> MA2, 5 -> EGW, 
   6 -> CST, 7 -> WHS, 8 -> HOT, 9 -> TSC, 10 -> FIN};
legends = {AGF, CO12, MA1, MA2, EGW, CST, WHS, HOT, TSC, FIN};

matrixlist = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6} = RandomReal[{0.1, 0.5}, {6, 10, 10}];


foo[a2, legends]
```

[image]

```
foo[#, legends] & /@ matrixlist // Short
```

[image]

Comment: I have to correct myself, very sorry. `subgraphBetweenCRI` should be `subgraphBetween` everywhere in `foo[...]` and after this correction, when I use matrix `a2`, for example, in `foo[a2, legends]`, the subscript `CRI` should be automatically replaced with matrix name `a2`. This would produce a completely defined output, which you have already produced. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer to my own question, but still, I am not satisfied with it because I cannot give an index name for each matrix in `out[...]`.

```
out[m_?MatrixQ] := {
   selectBetween[\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_] := BoolEval[\[Theta]1 <= m < \[Theta]2];
   subgraphBetween[\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_] := 
      AdjacencyGraph[selectBetween[\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2],
      PlotLabel -> \[Theta]1 <= Subscript[m, ij] < \[Theta]2, 
      VertexSize -> 0.3, VertexLabels -> vLabels, ImagePadding -> 20, 
      ImageSize -> 150];
{
  {"Weighted index of total number of links", 
  Sum[ \[Theta]1*EdgeCount[subgraphBetween[\[Theta]1, Max[m]]], {\[Theta]1, 0, 
   Max[m], 0.01}]},
  sectorCRI = {legends, Sum[\[Theta]1*
       DegreeCentrality[subgraphBetween[\[Theta]1, Max[m]]], {\[Theta]1, 0, 
       Max[m], 0.01}]}\[Transpose] // Reverse // TableForm,
  ListLinePlot[Table[{\[Theta]1, \[Theta]1*
    EdgeCount[subgraphBetween[\[Theta]1, Max[m]]]}, {\[Theta]1, 0,
    Max[m], 0.01}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"Threshold \nmultiplier: \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\
    \[Theta]\), \(CRI\)]\)", 
   "Weighted index \nof linkages: I(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\
   \), \(CRI\)]\))"}]
  }
 };
```